# WPF Data bound UI element not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, wcf, events

I have the following XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding SchedulerStatus, Mode=OneWay}" Width="150" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" />
    <Button Width="75" Height="30" Content="Test" Command="{Binding StartScheduler}" />
</StackPanel>
```

This is in a Window bound to this view model:

```
public class SchedulerViewModel : ViewModelBase // ViewModelBase implements INotifyPropertyChanged, using the [CallerMemberName] attribute.
{
    private readonly SchedulerServiceClient _proxy;

    public SchedulerViewModel()
    {
        _proxy = new SchedulerServiceClient();
        SchedulerStatusPoller poller = new SchedulerStatusPoller(this, _proxy);
    }

    private SchedulerStatus _schedulerStatus;
    internal SchedulerStatus SchedulerStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return _schedulerStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _schedulerStatus)
            {
                _schedulerStatus = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`SchedulerServiceClient` is a proxy to a WCF service that runs continually, and has a `Status` property that I need to watch. Because I cannot get callbacks from WCF to work after two solid days trying, I have implemented `SchedulerStatusPoller`, that periodically polls the WCF status, and updates the viewmodel status, in the hope that the display of the WCF status will be updated.

```
class SchedulerStatusPoller
{
    private static readonly Timer StatusTimer = new Timer(5000);
    private static SchedulerViewModel viewModel;
    private static SchedulerServiceClient proxy;

    public SchedulerStatusPoller(SchedulerViewModel targetViewModel, SchedulerServiceClient proxy)
    {
        SchedulerStatusPoller.proxy = proxy;
        viewModel = targetViewModel;
        StatusTimer.Elapsed += StatusTimerElapsed;
        StatusTimer.AutoReset = true;
        StatusTimer.Enabled = true;
        StatusTimer.Start();
    }

    void StatusTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        viewModel.SchedulerStatus = proxy.GetStatus();
    }
}
```

I have used the following code directly in the UI (the Window) that confirms that `PropertyChanged` is being raised by the `SchedulerViewModel`. The exception is thrown.

```
void _viewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((SchedulerViewModel)DataContext).SchedulerStatus = SchedulerStatus.Processing;
}
```

The poller does call into the `SchedulerStatus` property on the viewmodel every five seconds, but the textbox does not update. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh gawd! The whole - this part at least - problem was `internal SchedulerStatus`. It must be `public`.

Comment: yes the property have to be public !!

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention the source trigger

```
Text="{Binding SchedulerStatus, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: @ProfK . What about this proposition ?

Comment: No, I don't have to do that. Just make the property public, as you agreed in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your OnPropertyChanged inside the Setter is missing an argument. Shouldn't it be sth. like

PropertyChanged("SchedulerStatus");

Comment: If he uses the `CallerMemberName`-Attribute introduced with .Net 4.5 he doesn't need to provide the propertyname

Comment: Thank you, thats a fact i did not knew

Answer (score 0):

maybe,you can code it like this:

OnPropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SchedulerStatus"));